# What do all the treasures Sun Wukong got from the Dragon Kings do?

Tags: chinese, journey-to-the-west

I tried to look for information on them, but I can't find anything. Are they just strong pieces of armor or do they grant him special abilities?

Answer (score 3):

- The **cloud walking boots** allow him to fly *(although Wukong doesn't strictly need them to fly, having cultivated formidable powers of his own, and being able to cover 108,000 li in a single leap;)*

Likewise with the golden chainmail—Wukong's body subsequently becomes fairly invulnerable during his time in Laozi's eight-way trigram Crucible—but it never hurts to have some extra padding.

I can't recall if the **[phoenix feather cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A8ngch%C3%ACz%C7%90jingu%C4%81n)** granted any special powers, but, in any event, it was subsequently replaced by the gold circlet that [Xuanzan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuanzang_(Journey_to_the_West))g used to control him.

---

The unabridged Journey to the West is filled with detailed descriptions of the magical powers of objects, so it is likely more detail can be found in the text.  (When I get a chance to dig it out, I will re-read the passages and amend my answer:)

Comment: almost forgot his shoes... :). i read the original novel in Classical Chinese, really interested to know who did the best eng translation. his boots: 脚蹬藕丝步云履 - **cloud walking boots** *made of lotus silk* (very fragile thread could be obtained by tearing apart the lotus root, amazing how this nano stuff could stand thumping as shoes :D